# Deploying to Heroku with my persistence.xml (JPA) without using Spring

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, heroku, wildfly, persistence.xml

I have an error in application deployment with "git push master heroku" while locally it works fine.
I want to use my [persistence.xml](https://github.com/rubyonrails-tutorial/forge/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml) for access to my data base of H2 (I will be use maybe PostgreSQL) all with my data source on WildFly 10.

I found no reference other than the Spring. (I can not use it)

Thank you!

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38603284/heroku-deploy-with-java-jpa-not-use-spring

Comment: Hello everybody, please i want find the error.

Answer (score 1):

I've deployed JavaEE web app (with jsf, javabean, ejb, di etc) on Heroku. Heroku will **allow you to run shell script for starting your application** like class with a main method or executable .jar file. Not on the pre installed fullstack application server. Also if you gonna run java app on Heroku your project should be **maven**.

To **make it work from command line** you can use cloud ready run anywhere tiny servers like [payara-micro](http://www.payara.fish/payara_micro), [wildfly-swarm](http://wildfly-swarm.io/), [spring-boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/). It turns your app and server into single executable jar (Uber JAR). Also tomcat and jetty have wrappers for build uberJar.

I use payara-micro and it's great that very little jar can run **almost all of JavaEE features** with session replication. Follow this link for instructions [payara-micro how to](http://blog.payara.fish/creating-uber-jar-with-payara-micro) (read also maven parts).

When you git push to Heroku(with heroku cli tool) it will automatically builds your project and run script from file called **Procfile** from your project root directory. Sample procfile:

`web: java -jar target/myapp.jar --port $PORT`

Consider **`$PORT`** part from above snippet. When Heroku runtime (dyno) starts it will open random port (I think so) and bind to `$PORT` environment variable. So here I'm **passing** that accessibe port to payara-micro server for listen. Other mentioned servers should work with similar procedures. You can find documentations at [heroku devcenterr](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/java)

For JPA and database connectivity Heroku provides `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` and `DATABASE_URL` environment variables that have connection information (url etc) for you to [connect database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-java). I couln't find the way to hook up those variables into `persistence.xml`. But you can create and configure `EntityManagerFactory` and `EntityManager` programmatically.

Hope it helps.